# Can't figure out how to install my graphic drivers [Nvidia GT 520M]

Tags: nvidia

I give up, I've been reading forums all day and most of the stuff I've tried has led to a blank screen after logging in after reboot (No menus) which I've fixed by re-installing as I found it fastest as it was a fresh install anyways :P

My laptop is a Samsung NP-RV520-S02SE with a Nvidia GT 520M graphics card.

As you probably understand I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. I've also tried downloading the .run file from nvidia.com/drivers which gives me some error after loading for a while or I might be opening it wrong.

Any kind soul could help me out getting my drivers installed properly?

Comment: have you tried installing the driver from Nvidias site or directly from "Additional drivers" in Ubuntu?. Also: which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: This is what I get

`totte@Totte-Ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520M] (rev a1)`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and yes, I've tried installing from Nvidias site. Haven't tried "Additional drivers", not sure which one to chose.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T EVER INSTALL DRIVERS DIRECTLY FROM NVIDIA OR AMD

I will assume you didn't install anything. In the terminal run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

---

*If your card is NOT Optimus enabled* run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-313 nvidia-settings
```

reboot

---

*If your card IS Optimus enabled* run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

reboot

Comment: No I did not install anything, simply fresh install. That give me weird resolution again, where I can't see any menus or anything :/ Then is said "Graphics: VESA somethingsomething" in the Details thing. It asked me to update, so I did, then rebooted and the resolution went back to normal but now it says "Graphics: Unknown" again :P

Comment: Though stuff as the Dashboard menu feels way faster now.. ;o

Comment: In terminal run: `sudo nvidia-xconfig` logout and back in (or possibly reboot... not sure)

Comment: So I did, said some file didn't exist so it created it, then I rebooted. Not sure what that did though :P

Comment: After you created the empty xorg.conf file did you run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` again? The "Graphics Unknown" thing in "System Settings > Details" is a harmless bug. You can fix it by running `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`. Other than that is everything running ok?

Comment: Yep, everything appears to be working as it should now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Please close the question so that others may find an answer quickly.

Comment: How do I close it? =P I'm blind, can't find it anywhere.

Comment: had to google it myself. I'm new here. There should be a tick mark next to an answer (I don't see it since its not my question). Click it to accept the answer.