# NVIDIA Geforce GT 520M driver

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

how to install NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M driver on ubuntu 13.10?
i want this graphic driver for steam's games

Comment: There is a guide [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/258434/164718) . But the Question is a Duplicate. Follow the Previous question also.

Answer (score 0):

in short, first install bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

then you can run steam with your nvidia graphics:

```
optirun steam
```

this process will allow you to utilize Optimus (that's whats bumblebee is for) and then you can manually run applications with your nvidia card using the optirun command.